# AWS cognito authentication flow with React frontend and Go backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm building a web app that has a React frontend and a Go backend; I'd like to build out the backend to call services and do other things instead of just having a front-end based app. To my understanding from some other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391391/token-based-authentication-application-vs-server), the authentication flow should be as follows:

1. Client inputs username and password
2. Frontend calls AWS Cognito user pool to verify credentials. If correct, JWT tokens are sent back to frontend.
3. The frontend sends these tokens to the backend
4. The backend verifies the tokens and checks the access token is valid.
5. If valid, the backend then uses the ID token for other services.

Is this correct? If so, then I'll need a Javascript + Go Cognito SDK?

Furthermore, it seems AWS has Cognito support for [Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/) but I don't see docs for just Javascript or Go. I did find functions in the [Javascript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html) and [Go](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/cognitoidentityprovider/#CognitoIdentityProvider.GetUser) SDK, though; however, I couldn't find examples how to use them properly. Would anyone know of a good resource?

Comment: AWS Amplify has [good support](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/react/) for React and a bunch of other front end libraries.  Your basic flow is OIDC/Oauth and you've got it correct.  Amplify is a bit challenging but it can be done - just be patient.

Comment: I see. But I read that Amplify is for serverless web apps, whereas I intend on creating a lot of functionality with my backend (implementing complex algorithms and data structures, classes, etc.)?

Comment: If you want to use Amplify dig into the [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/js/) a bit.  There is support for [Rest](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/getting-started/q/platform/js/) and [GraphQL](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/getting-started/q/platform/js/) along with persistent store and, yes, serverless too if you'd like.